# Typescript: Infer type of nested keyof Properties

Tags: typescript, type-inference, keyof

I want to define an Array type that must contain a chain of nested property names of a given type.

Let's say I have a type:

```
    type Foo = {
        outer: {
            inner: any;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to define an Array type with 2 elements:

```
type PropertyList<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]> = [K1, K2];
```

I want to use it like this:

```
let myList:PropertyList<Foo> = ["outer", "inner"]
```

So I want the compiler to check if the 2 contained Property names are nested property names of Foo.

But I can't define PropertyList with only 1 generic parameter, I get this error then:

```
TS2314: Generic type 'PropertyList' requires 3 type argument(s)
```

Any idea how i can infer the nested keyof types without having to specify them?

Answer (score 3):

A first approximation of how to do this is in Tao's answer, the problem is that if you add more properties it does not work as expected:

```
type Foo = {
    outer: {
        inner: any;
    }
    outer2: {
        inner2: any;
    }
}

type PropertyList<T, K1 extends keyof T = keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1] = keyof T[K1]> = [K1, K2];

let myList:PropertyList<Foo> = ["outer", "inner"] // error, since K2 will have to be a property of both outer and outer2
```

You can use function to help with inferring the corect type based on the actual parameters passed. We need to use a two function approach because we need to have generic parameters for `T`, `K1` and `K2`, but we only want to specify `T` and if we specify one we must specify all parameters:

```
function pathFor<T>() {
    return  function <K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>(outer: K1, inner: K2): [K1,K2]{
        return  [outer, inner];
    }
}
// Usage 
let myList = pathFor<Foo>()("outer", "inner"); // typed as ["outer, "inner"]
let myList2 = pathFor<Foo>()("outer2", "inner"); // error, inner is not part of outer2
let myList3 = pathFor<Foo>()("outer2", "inner2"); // typed as ["outer2, "inner2"]
```

**Edit**

You can also expand the function to take paths up to a finite length (4 in the example, but add more as needed):

```
function keysFor<T>() {
    function keys<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2], K4 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3]>(outer: K1, inner: K2, innerInner: K3, innerInnerInner: K4): [K1,K2, K3, K4]
    function keys<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2]>(outer: K1, inner: K2, innerInner: K3): [K1,K2, K3]
    function keys<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]>(outer: K1, inner: K2): [K1,K2]
    function keys(): string[]{
        return [...arguments];
    }
    return keys
}
```

Comment: This "two function approach" is a brilliant workaround to the lack of support for partial generic argument specification.  I'd like to be able to assign a type to `myList`, though, such that it can hold the results of any call to `pathFor<Foo>()(...)`.  I'm still working on figuring out that declaration.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

I think I misunderstood your question and don't think that's possible (yet). Maybe inferring the positional types will be possible with [type inference for conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) that will be included in the upcoming version 2.8 of TypeScript.

I will leave the original answer below just in case.

---

Type parameters can have default values:

```
type PropertyList<T, K1 extends keyof T = keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1] = keyof T[K1]> = [K1, K2];
```

But maybe in your case it makes more sense to not specify `K1` and `K2` as type parameters:

```
type PropertyList<T> = [keyof T, keyof T[keyof T]];
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer so maybe the result is dependent on TS version, but in my experiments `keyof T[keyof T]` is always `never` regardless of what constraints you place on `T`. ETA: never mind, I think Titian's answer clarifies the problem.